# instructions for+gerund/on how

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

> The HLA-B gene provides **instructions for making** a protein that plays a critical role in the immune system. HLA-B is part of a family of genes called the human leukocyte antigen (HLA) complex. The HLA complex helps the immune system distinguish the body's own proteins from proteins made by foreign invaders such as viruses and bacteria.

Hey, y'all, the text you see above is taken from an article on the HLA-B gene. Would the meaning change if I replace the bolded part with "**instructions on how to make** a protein"?

Answer (score 3):

It means roughly the same, but it's less precise.

*Instructions for making the protein* implies that if you follow these instructions you will make the protein.

*Instructions on how to make the protein* says that the instructions are somehow involved in making the protein, but does not make clear how they are involved - are they are the whole story, or is something else needed?

The second form could be used if the instructions are complete, of course, but pragmatically, the choice of this less precise expression gives an impression that the speaker intended not to be precise.

Comment: I think the difference between singular / plural ***instruction/s*** is relevant to why [***instructions on how to make*** is gaining ground on ***instructions for making***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=instructions+on+how+to+make%2Cinstructions+for+making&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) The *singular* "on how to" version [has already displaced "for".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=instruction+on+how+to+make%2Cinstruction+for+making&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: ...but realistically, I'd say *instructions **on how to make** X* would almost always mean *exactly* the same as *instructions **for making** X*